# Apache serve service from local host on subdomain

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, hosting

I am trying to use Apache to serve multiple sites at the same time, the structure I want to obtain is composed by a main site at `example.com` and use the subdomains `radarr.example.com` and `sonarr.example.com` to access my Radarr and Sonarr servers.

The main site is hosted on **machine1**, I set up a virtual host using apache and certbot:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  
  WSGIDaemonProcess sflasksite user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/webapp/app.wsgi

  <Directory /var/www/webapp>
    WSGIProcessGroup sflasksite
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /static /var/www/webapp/static

  <Directory /var/www/webapp/static/>
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/www/webapp/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/webapp/logs/access.log combined


SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The two servers I want to serve are on **machine2**, on the same network as **machine1**, how can I obtain the two services respectively on `radarr.example.com` and `sonarr.example.com`?

After some reading, I tried to use a **Reverse Proxy**, configuring a virtual host for each service as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  
  ServerAlias radarr.example.com

  ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.20:7878/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.20:7878/

  ErrorLog /var/www/radarr/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/radarr/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and alike for Sonarr.

However, when I navigate to `radarr.example.com`, I do not get the expected service but the main site.

How can I get the reverse proxy to work? Or should I switch to another strategy altogether?

EDIT:
I am also open to abandon apache if someone knows and can suggest a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: Remember that you have to define vhost for http and https. Or possibly only https even today.

Comment: check "apachectl -S" for virtualhosts defined. All Virtualhosts must have a ServerName directive, apache checkts Host header, the first virtualhost matching replies the answer, so it must be your "default" virtualhost has a greedy ServerAlias name or similar.

Comment: @DanielFerradal What ServerName should I put in the reverseproxy config? The servername in the "default" virtualhost is example.com (obv not really example but my hostname, just to be clear).

Comment: You should put what you want to enter in the URL field of the browser to reach that vhost.

Comment: @vidarlo I tried that, I put radarr.example.com in ServerName and commented out ServerAlias and now I simply cannot connect

Comment: If you can't connect you have a mistake that stops Apache from starting. What's the output of `apachectl configtest`?

Comment: @vidarlo sorry I meant that I can't connect to radarr.example.com, the main site is up and running

Comment: Then you have a DNS issue. Can you please [edit] your question with the *real* domains?

Comment: @vidarlo I would prefer not to share the real domain, I have defined two CNAME dns entries, named radarr and sonarr on my cloudflare dashboard

Comment: @RiccardoBarbieri whichever matches the hostname you want to represent but it most not match any further virtualhost servername. For example, use default as www.example.com (AND NOT ServerAlias *.example.com) and your specific virtualhost like somethingelse.example.com. That way when someone requests somethingelse.example.com Apache will know which virtualhost to use. "apachectl -S" should give you enough clues.

Comment: @DanielFerradal I tried to do what you suggested but I still have the same problem, even though I have example.com as ServerName in the main VirtualHost and radarr.example.com in the secondary VirtualHost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem I was having was due to the fact that I installed ssl certificates only for the domain mydomain.com and not the domain radarr.mydomain.com. I run certbot again for that domain and now it works.

I don't exactly know why it works, if someone has an explanation, please post it and I will add it to the answer.